# Angular Upload FROM google drive

Tags: angular, upload, google-drive-api

In an Angular (v7) app I'm developing, I currently have a standard upload feature using ng-file-upload.  The files go to my web server, etc.  Now, I'd like to add the ability for users to upload directly from Google Drive, much like Slack does.  Most things I find on the internet are about uploading TO drive, but I want to upload FROM drive to my own server.  Does anyone know of any Angular libraries that deal with this?  If not, are there any good tutorials for this?

I know that if a user has drive synced to their device, those files would be accessible for upload just like any other since the current upload functionality opens a file picker.  However, I'm trying to enable users to upload from drive without having the files synced to their device.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will need to go through an OAuth flow in order for the user to grant permission to your app to access his Drive. This will result in an Access Token. Pass this to your server, along with the ID of the file to be uploaded. Your server can then use the Access Token to fetch the file.

The Google Drive Picker does some of the heavy lifting. https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/